# number theory with algebra

Tags: number-theory

there are some very tough problems in the number theory book i am solving through.

Here is one of them.

Find three distinct positive integers with the least possible sum such that the sum of the reciprocals of any two integers among them is an integral multiple of the reciprocal of the third integer.

Comment: how about 1, 1, and 1?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein The OP mentions *distinct positive integers.

Comment: I took 3 distinct positive integers as x,y and z, such that x<y<z. Then, i wrote all three possible conditions, which are                     1/x + 1/y = a/z  ;  1/y + 1/z = b/x  ;  1/x + 1/z = c/y , in which a,b,c are some positive integers.                                     Then, after calculating further, i got                                  1/x + 1/y + 1/z = (a+1)/z = (b+1)/x = (c+1)/y = k , where k is any positive integer. But, I am not able to go further with the problem. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** If you have three distinct integers, $x,y,z$ that satisfy the condition, without loss of generality assume $x<y<z$ and notice you have
$$
1/y+1/z=a/x, \,\,\,\, 1/z+1/x=b/y,\,\,\,\,\,1/x+1/y=c/z
$$
for some integers $a,b,c$. Try getting these all equal to a common number and use the ordering on $x,y,z$ to get an ordering on $a,b,c$. After some algebra, you should get something that looks like
$$
\frac{1}{\text{something with a}}+\frac{1}{\text{something with b}}+\frac{1}{\text{something with c}}=1
$$
then notice that $a<\text{some number}$ to find your smallest case. However, I'm sure this can be done easily using divisibility or perhaps with some 'meatier' tools from Analytic/Algebraic Number Theory.

EDIT: I'll help you out a bit.

$1.$ Given those first three things, you must have
$$
\frac{a+1}{x},\frac{b+1}{y},\frac{c+1}{z}
$$
all equal to the same number, call it what you will. What other simple sum using $x,y,z$ does your number, call it $N$ have to be?

$2$. Set this sum with $x,y,z$ equal to the three I mentioned above then solve for $1/x,1/y,1/z$. Then add these three equalities so that your original important sum, $1/x+1/y+1/z$ becomes a sum of three fractions with $N$ in the numerator and some sum with one of $a,b,c$ in the denominator, respectively.

$3$. Because $x<y<z$ by assumption, $a<b<c$ ad we have
$$
1=\frac{1}{a+1}+\frac{1}{b+1}+\frac{1}{c+1}
$$
(so you know where you're going). Then follow my original last hint. The solution then follows almost immediately.

Comment: I am not able to understand the solution given by you, sir. Please explain the complete solution in detail. Thank you.

Comment: @WilliamGeorge I won't do it for you. But I did give a more detailed, extensive hint.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I will try to solve the problem from where you left it for me

Comment: @WilliamGeorge No problem and good luck! You know you're on the right track if each step is very simple.